# Add two values from one table then insert into a new column on another table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

The goal is to add two values from an existing table, then have the sum value replace the value from the existing table to make the new file my boss wants.

All while keeping the data from the existing table as is...only updating the new one.

After looking around online I started working on an insert statement like the one below:

```sql
insert into temptable1 (col1, col2,col3, col4,col5,col6,col7,col8)
        select col1, col2, max(col3), max(col4),max(col5),max(col6),max(col7),max(col8)                                 
        from temptable2
        group by col1, col2
```

then tried updating the table with the sums:

```sql
Update t1
        Set t1.col8 = t2.col8
        FROM temptable1 t1
        INNER JOIN (select col1, col2, sum(col6 + col7) as col8
        from temptable2 group by col1, col2) as t2
        on t2.col1 = t1.col1

Update t1
        Set t1.col5 = t2.col5
        FROM temptable1 t1
        INNER JOIN (select col1, col2, sum(col3 + col4) as col5
        from temptable2 group by col1, col2) as t2
        on t2.col1 = t1.col1
```

Afterwards it goes into another insert statement that talks to the related perma tables in the database. I can execute this without getting any errors but the report I'm getting as a result of this script doesn't look unchanged in the slightest.

temtable2 in this example is the one that would have existing data, temptable1 is the one that should have the summations.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server; what RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: Nobody would be able to help you until they have your table structure and sample data. Please create a DBFiddle and share your sample data to get better help.

Comment: If the updates don't then  on t2.col1 = t1.col1 may not be true or one of the 2 values summed might be 0 or you may not be dealing with nulls and why are you maxing col5 and col8 in the insert and then attempting to overwrite in the updates- ie we need data..

Comment: Its really SQL Server,
I'll look into DBFiddle,
The maxing is only there because of an aggregate error i was getting. i understood it enough to know it was looking for something like that, but definitely not enough to know what it actually needs. What you are saying makes sense though so that's for sure one issue out of the million here lol. Thank you.